# How can I select this joined list in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table.

t_family

```
ID     Employee   
A1     John
A2     Gladys
```

t_sibling

```
ID     Name       Status
A1     Darco      Brother
A1     Carmen     Sister
A1     Clara      Sister
A2     Luther     Brother
```

I'd like to make a list by selecting Employee and Name column.

```
SELECT (this code i'm looking for) AS Family, Status from t_family INNER JOIN t_sibling ON t_family.ID = t_sibling.ID
```

The output

```
Family      Status
John        Employee
Darco       Brother
Carmen      Sister
Clara       Sister
Gladys      Employee
Luther      Brother
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

**Note:**
can I do it without union? just a join. I have speed issue with union. Especially the data will be hundred thousands

Comment: Check your question i think on output there will no employee result as its column name ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman well, if there are no status (NULL) then change it to 'Employee'

Comment: can I do it without union? just a join. I have speed issue with union. Especially the data will be hundred thousands

Comment: Can't see a way to do it without using UNION

Answer (score 0):

use union to get your desired output from both table like below

```
select Employee as Name,status 
from 
(
select id,Employee ,'Employee 'as status from t1

union all

select id,Name,status from t2
)
order by id asc
```